# Архитектура изоморфного Java Script приложения

Tags: javascript, node.js

Хочу создать небольшой проект включающий в себя: API для мобильных приложений и frontend, frontend на React. Не могу понять как лучше организовать архитектуру приложения, вынести RESTful часть в отдельный проект и соответственно pепозиторий или делать все в одном проекте и репозитории. Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше поступить в этом случаи и как поступать для сложных проектов?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше разнести по разным проектам, ну и соответственно репозиториям.